# ElasticSearch: Find record with multiple conditions on a list of sub-elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm saving documents like this to ElasticSearch:

```json
[
  {
    "text": "Sam works for Google.",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text": "Sam",
        "type": "PERSON"
      },
      {
        "text": "Google",
        "type": "ORGANIZATION"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It's essentially a sentence and entities that appear in that sentence. Now, I want to find any document that has entities of type "PERSON" `AND` "ORGANIZATION". I tried a boolean `must` query:

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "entities.type": "PERSON"
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "entities.type": "ORGANIZATION"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

... but that seems to try to look for entities that that are of both types, which obviously returns nothing. How do I need to formulate my query?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't entities.type be used instead of entities__type

Comment: Yes. That was a typo. But the problem here is larger. It still filters for entities that are of both types. But an entity can only be of one type.

Comment: @chris, can you share your mapping and some sample documents and expected results to understand your requirements better, at first look it seems you need https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: can you add a sample document which should appear in result but is not retrived

Comment: @chris can you add information which is required to provide you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below query as your original query dont have correct field name.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entities.type": "PERSON"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entities.type": "ORGANIZATION"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```